# What's the best way to parse an interval from a string?

Tags: postgresql, parsing, casting, intervals

What's the most direct way get an interval from a string (varchar) value in postgres?

I have a column that contains JSON data. One of the JSON properties is a "runtime" value that is formatted like: `"runtime":"03s.684"`. Using the JSON functions I'll able to get to just the runtime value with no problem, but then I've got the quoted string value.

I was looking for something similar to `to_timestamp()` so I could parse the string doing something like:

```
select to_interval('"03s.684"', '"SS\s.MS"'); --would like to do / this function doesn't exist
```

or something like this would be nice too:

```
select to_timestamp('"03s.684"', '"SS\s.MS"') :: interval; --also not valid
```

One approach I can see that should work is to translate the string into a format that can be cast to interval using `regexp_replace()` but that doesn't seem like the best approach. What's the recommended way of getting an interval from a custom-formatted time string?

Comment: I forgot to mention the reason for needing an interval value is to be able to perform aggregate functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`to_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html)

```
SELECT to_number('3s.684', '999D9099') * '1 second'::interval;
```

Comment: Aha! This is what I was looking for. Thanks!